# Problem with uploading my own model in forge autodesk

Tags: file-upload, data-visualization, autodesk-forge, forge

Good morning,
I'm trying to create my own app with Autodesk Forge but i'm having trouble with replacing the default model with my own. I'm following this tutorial https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/replace_model/
i followed all the instructions but when i write localhost:9000/upload in my browser it appears the default model and not the page with the button browse to upload the file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to make the `/upload` URL accessible, you need to follow the steps explained in the tutorial:

- Create a copy of the *server/env_template* file and name it *server/.env*
- Add your Forge credentials to the *server/.env* file
- Run the application with the `ENV=local` env. variable

  - If you're using a Unix-like terminal, run `ENV=local npm run dev` from the project folder
  - If you're on Windows, I'd suggest installing [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org), and use the Git Bash terminal to run the same command as above

Btw. if you simply want to get started with Forge, there are many tutorials out there that are easier to setup, for example, https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io.